# Scroll until element is in DOM

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Hi there I'm using this code to try and scroll the page until element is in the DOM. However it the page doesn't scrol, it just loops and loops over. Is my `IJavaScriptExecutor` wrong?

```
public static void ScrollUntilElementinDom(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
{
    bool isPresent = false;
    while (isPresent == false)
    {
        try
        {
            isPresent = driver.FindElement(by).Displayed;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        if (isPresent == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(100,0);");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Note: the element is not in the dom, a scroll will trigger the element.

Answer (score 2):

- You are scrolling the window to trigger loading of further content.
- You wish to continue scrolling the window, until the content you seek has been loaded.

You need to **wait for the content to load**.

At no point are you waiting. Consider `WebDriverWait`

Comment: correct. However I don't see how webdriverwait would be useful, a while loop should suffice right?

Comment: Okay i'll insert a pause. However my Javascript does not scroll the page, would you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to scroll with `Actions`

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(by)).Build().Perform();
```

And to find if the element is displayed you can use explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

try
{
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
    isPresent = true;
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

This will wait up to 15 seconds for the element to be visible.

Comment: The only caveat to using Actions (in this case) is that IT is a "native browser event".  You might get faster/different/better results using a non-native JavascriptExecutor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Actions class to perform scrolling to element.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("element-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```